# Classic ASP Iterate through and Object

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, recordset

I'm a PHP developer, learning ASP.
I've become very reliant on PHP's useful functions: `print_r()` and `var_dump()` to see what an array or object contains.

I don't always know what columns are in a Db Table. So, when a `SELECT * From Tbl` is queried, and the **objRS** is populated, would I be able to view what the entire object's contents are?

Is this possible in ASP?

```
<% `my simple Select statement 
Dim strDbConnection
Dim objConn
Dim objRS
Dim strSQL
strDbConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\test.mdb;"
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open(strDbConnection)
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM persons"
Set objRS = objConn.Execute(strSQL)
If objRS.EOF Then
  Response.Write("No items found")
Else
  Do While Not objRS.EOF

    ' show all columns I can extract here....

    objRS.MoveNext()
  Loop
End If
objRS.Close()
Set objRS = Nothing
objConn.Close()
Set objConn = Nothing
%>
```

-- I would like to see what's coming back at me in the **objRS**, and then cherry-pick the columns after I know what I have access to.

Is there something similar to what I'm used to?
ie: `print_r()`

Comment: Direct answer: VBScript does not have equivalent, however JScript does, with `for (var prop in obj)` which iterates all the properties of given object. You can combine JScript with VBScipt but it's bit complicated - if all you need is this specific thing (field names) go with the answer you got, if you want more generic approach let me know and I'll give some basic example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use objRS.fileds(j).name and objRS.fields(j).value to get the name of columns and values.
For example:

```
  [...]
  for j = 0 to objRS.fields.count - 1
     response.write(objRS.fields(j).name & " = " & objRS.fields(j).value)
  next
```